# Can I restart the USB stack on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I am developing a USB 3.0 audio device. However, the current state of the firmware is so buggy, that often Windows crashes or stops enumerating new devices, stops detecting disconnected devices, etc.

Is there a way to restart the USB 3.0 hub? Or the whole USB bus?

Comment: What firmware are we talking about exactly?  This question has been asked before on Stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987958/how-do-i-reset-usb-devices-using-the-windows-api

Comment: @Ramhound, no, I need to restart the **host USB stack/hardware**. Btw, I just tried restarting the USB 3.0 hub and Windows shut down automatically. :(